# jqxgrid- pager renderer

Tags: jqxgrid

I would like to add extrabutton in the pager without disturbing the default ui elements such as
1) Gotopage
2) show rows
3) paging info etc.,

I can write custom pagerrenderer. but it increases my code space by rewriting althose functionalities which are present in pager.js.
Could you please help as I was new to this grids

Answer (score 0):

The id of the div default pager is 'pager', so you can try add elements into the div. This work for me : 
Html :

```
<div id="jqxgrid"></div>
<div id="custonPager">
    <a class="jq-btn" id="btnRefresh"><i class="icon-refresh"></i></a>
</div>
```

JS Code

```
// init jqxgrid
$("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid({..});
//add custom buttons in pager div
$("#pager").children().each(function(){
    $(this).append($("#custonPager").children());
});
$(".jq-btn").jqxButton();
```